# Jboss drools - Can I have multiple consequences in "then" condition and fire the rules?

Tags: java, drools

I'm relatively very new to drools and have a requirement where I need to execute both consequences for my rule.

Creating new requests W and F.

Consequence in `.dsl` file

```
[consequence][]Create W Request for Cash=$out.setNewPayload(requestFactory.submitWReq($message));
[consequence][]Create F Request for Cash=$out.setNewPayload(requestFactory.submitFReq($message));
```

`.dslr` file
I have created a rule here which has both consequences in the same rule, but

```
rule "Send an incoming request to WF"
when
    There is an incoming message
    Not routed yet
then
   Create W Request for Cash
   Route to "WQueue".
   Create F Request for Cash
   Route to "RQueue".
```

This problem with having multiple consequence in the rule is that same "request" is being sent to both the routes (Queues). First the code flows through the `requestFactory.submitWReq` method and then `submitFReq($message)` method, so whatever modifications done in former method will get overridden by the later method and routed to the Queues. The reason also for having two consequence is because certain modifications are made to the request which are sent to W and F queues.

**Now, if I write two rules:**

```
W rule:

rule "Send an incoming request to W"
when
    There is an incoming message
    Not routed yet
then
   Create W Request for Cash
   Route to "WQueue".

F Rule:

rule "Send an incoming request to F"
when
    There is an incoming message
    Not routed yet
then
   Create F Request for Cash
   Route to "RQueue".
```

Only one rule, either W or F is getting executed if two rules are present in the .dslr file. My requirement is to make sure that both the rules get executed. The `when` condition is same for both the rule, only the `then` varies.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Route rule**

```
[*][]Not routed yet=$out : Router(hasNotRoutes == true)
[consequence][]Route to {routeNames}\.=modify($out) \{addRoute({routeNames})\};
```

Answer (score 0):

**The answer to the question in the title:**

Everything in the rule consequences ("then" clause, also called the "right hand side") gets executed. So yes, you can have multiple consequences in the 'then' clause and they will all fire.

---

**The answer to the question in the body:**

However your "route to <queue>" action is defined, it's not correctly identifying the request generated immediately previous. Maybe you have asynchronous processing involved and you're hitting a race condition, I don't know -- you haven't shared how "route to..." is defined, and even your "create ... request..." action is vague.

Your two-rule solution won't work because of the 'Not routed yet' condition. Once the 'send to F' rule is triggered, 'not routed yet' is no longer accurate, so 'send to W' is not valid to fire; the reverse is also true. You can solve this issue in your two-rule solution by changing the 'not routed yet' condition to instead be defined something like "Not routed yet or only previously routed to W/F" (where "W/F" is the other route.) Could do it with 4 rules, this way as well, but that's getting complex.

I'd suggest fixing your actions to properly create and send the requests and have a single rule.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the route rule above. Could you tell me how to add only previously routed to W/F ? is it like this ?  `[*][]Only previously routed to W=$out :Router(routes contains "WQueue")`. OR `[*][]Only previously routed to F=$out :Router(routes contains "FQueue")`

Comment: this is condition for Not routed yet - `[*][]Not routed yet=$out : Router(hasNotRoutes == true)`

Comment: If I create something like this , then it goes to infinite loop -> `[*][]If routed already=$out : Router(hasNotRoutes == false)`